# How to enable a href link on click of a button in JavaScript not in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, image, hyperlink, href

Initially href link is diasabled, when I click on the image nothing happens. But when I click on a button, the link should get enabled. The Href link is opening a JavaScript calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code on click of your button

```
document.getElementById('linkName').setAttribute("href","http://www.foo.com");
```

Replace linkName with the id of your link and change the url string.

Hope this works for ya.